# Global navigation layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, navigation, lightningnavigation

Desktop - The global navigation component that is  available on the sdfc is a horizontal tab.
Can I change the global navigation layout to a global vertical navigation(sticky)during development??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce you won't be able to do that.

If you talking about experiences/community, then some templates provide that option OR you can spin up your own custom component using Navigation Sets or interface provided by Salesforce.